# How to make an UIView come top to bottom and vice versa on drag

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to do an animation where a UIView should come from top to bottom(or till mid of screen) when we toch on top of the screen and drag down.

Answer (score 1):

Set your view frame, and then add these code in your button action or else.

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [yourView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 250, 320, 100)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0):

set positions according to ur need

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"DragView" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
self.dragView.frame = CGRectMake(newXPose, newYPose,width, height);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```